# react native code push rollback not working

Tags: react-native, code-push

I want to rollback the last code-push with this command:

```
code-push rollback appName Staging
```

But i got this error:

```
Cannot perform rollback to a different app version. Please perform a new release with the desired replacement package.
```

I can make another release but i want to know to how to work with rollBack.